# Elm union subsets

Tags: elm, union-types

Say I have a union type like this:

```
type Route
  = Home
  | License
  | UserProfile { username : String }
  | Search { query : String }
  | SomeOtherPage
```

In practice I frequently need to work with *subsets* of this union. For example:

```
type StaticRoute = Home | License
```

I would like to be able to define functions which accept subsets like the above, instead of the wider `Route`.

I don't want to nest `StaticRoute` inside of `Route`, like so:

```
type Route
  = Static StaticRoute
  | UserProfile { username : String }
  | Search { query : String }
  | SomeOtherPage
```

This is because I want to be able to define many different subsets of `Route`, some of which could overlap:

```
type StaticRoute = Home | License
type RouteWithServerRendering = Home | Search { query : String }
type LoggedInRoute = SomeOtherPage
-- and so on…
```

How then can I define subsets of `Route` without repeating definitions?

Comment: I think you can just define functions of type `Route -> Bool` and then test using them.

Comment: You can't. That's simply not a feature of the language, and for good reason I think. OCaml supports this, with a feature called [polymorphic variants](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-400/manual006.html#toc36) but it quickly gets complicated because the variance, how they should "match" with other subsets or supersets, depend on how they are used. It's also pretty error-prone since a small typo might make a different subset and because type annotations aren't mandatory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Jasper Woudenberg](https://dev.to/jwoudenberg) recently posted [Conversion functions, five stars](https://dev.to/jwoudenberg/conversion-functions-five-stars-2l87)
, which advocates for having similar types and using conversion functions to translate between one type to another.

In your case, it might look like this:

```
module Route exposing (fromStaticRoute, toStaticRoute)

fromStaticRoute : StaticRoute -> Route
fromStaticRoute staticRoute =
    case staticRoute of
        Static.Home ->
            Home
        Static.License ->
            License

toStaticRoute : Route -> Maybe StaticRoute
toStaticRoute route =
    case route of
        Home ->
            Just Static.Home
        License ->
            Just Static.License
        _ ->
            Nothing
```